# Lua Import Data from File, Convert Data from File to Array

Tags: lua

I need to import data from file into an array.

The file contains some random hex codes separated by spaces

```
Line 1: D8 A7 9D 5E
Line 2: 87 2F A4 7E
Line 3: 77 32 12 95
```

I need to be able to index the different values such that D8 would correspond to index [1] and 87 to index [5]. Or is there a way in Lua to convert this multi-line data into a single stream of data, so it would be easier to index?

Answer (score 2):

Adapt this code to your needs:

```
assert(io.input"myfile")
local T=io.read"*a"
local a={}
local n=0
for x in T:gmatch("%x%x") do
    n=n+1
    a[n]=x
end
```

This code assumes that the file contains only the hex codes, not the `Line xxx:` prefixes.

Comment: Yes, the Line xxx: prefixes are not included, just the values. The code you have suggested works well, was able to try the code and get the values based on their index. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, @lhf, after indexing the values, how could I separate for example the value at index [1] which is D8 into individual values D and 8?

Comment: @HephaestusMariani. if you want separate values, use `"%x"` instead of `"%x%x"`.